# How do I vote to reopen?

Tags: discussion

Per [this help page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions), I can vote to reopen a question, as I have over 3000 rep, but I cannot see a way to do so.  I do have the option to edit the question, but I don't think the question needs editing.  I'd like to put the question in the reopen queue with comments; can I do so?

Specifically, [slds-form-element_horizontal change distribution of label and field](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/298650/slds-form-element-horizontal-change-distribution-of-label-and-field) asks, "Is it possible to change the distribution of the label (default is 33/66%) in a horizontal form?" and is tagged `lightning-web-components`.  The question was closed as a duplicate of [Target inner elements of standard Lightning Web Components with CSS](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/246887/target-inner-elements-of-standard-lightning-web-components-with-css), however, this question can be answered without targeting inner elements of LWCs, by [adding a utility class (`slds-form-element_1-col`) from Lightning Design System](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/form-element/#Single-Column-Support) to the lightning component (or at least, it can be answered partially - I'm not sure this solution would help the original poster, but it would help some folks searching for the same question).  I've tested this with `lightning:input` and `lightning:combo-box`; I assume it will work with any standard `lightning:*` component that supports `variant="label-inline"`.  I'd like to document this solution here, as I don't think it directly addresses the other (linked) question, but cannot unless it is reopened.

Answer (score 2):

There should be a 'reopen' link underneath the question body, in the same row as 'share' and 'edit'. This is how it looks for me (on another site, I don't have enough reputation here):

[image]

It's a good practice to leave a comment *why* you think the question needs reopening, to help the reviewers in the Reopen Votes review queue. They will see all of the question's comments in the queue.

Comment: Thanks, I was too busy looking in the big blue "This question already has answers" box to notice the little grey reopen link.  It is in fact present.  When you mention  the best practice of commenting, is that the standard comment link below the question (like this comment!), or something that happens once you click 'reopen')?

Comment: That's the standard comment link. The dialog does not offer such an option.